# Why does [NSNumber numberWithInt:INFINITY] return 0?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to use the INFINITY macro as an integer but for some reason it returns 0.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<100; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:INFINITY]); //return -/+ max int
}

for (int i = 0 ; i<100; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:INFINITY]); //return "inf"
}
```

What's the proper usage of INFINITY? I thought it'd return a maximum integer or float value and -INFINITY would return a negative minimum integer or float value but definitely not 0. Why does it return 0?

Comment: INFINITY is infinity, a special value that can be represented by float or double floating point formats. It's not convertible to integer because integer cannot represent infinity. It has nothing to do with maximum integer. Maximum integer have a separate macro constant.

Comment: Look into `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` if that's what you want.

Comment: What would you expect it to return? 100? 1000? Which number do you want? Which number is high enough for your infinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

INFINITY is a special value that can be represented by float or double floating point formats.

It's not convertible to an integer because integers cannot represent infinity.

`numberWithInt` has been written so that it returns zero since it can't make sense out of infinity in an int.

Comment: Thanks @sulthan and @almo!